# Filling gaps based on gap length

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series

I am currently playing with financial data, missing financial data specifically. What I'm trying to do is fill the gaps basing on gap length, for example:
- if length of the gap is lower than 5 NaN, then interpolate
- if length is > 5 NaN, then fill with values from different series

So what I am trying to accomplish here is a function that will scan series for NaN, get their length and then fill them appropriately. I just wanted to push as much as I can to pandas/numpy ops and not do it in loops etc...

Below just example, this is not optimal at all:

```
ser = pd.Series(np.sort(np.random.uniform(size=100)))
ser[48:52] = None
ser[10:20] = None

def count(a):
    tmp = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        current=a[i]
        if not(np.isnan(current)) and tmp>0:
            a[(i-tmp):i]=tmp
            tmp=0
        if np.isnan(current):
            tmp=tmp+1

g = ser.copy()
count(g)
g[g<1]=0

df = pd.DataFrame(ser, columns=['ser'])
df['group'] = g
```

Now we want to interpolate when gap is < 10 and put something where gap > 9

```
df['ready'] = df.loc[df.group<10,['ser']].interpolate(method='linear')
df['ready'] = df.loc[df.group>9,['ser']] = 100
```

To sum up, 2 questions:
- can Pandas do it robust way?
- if not, what can you suggest to make my way more robust and faster? Lets just focus on 2 points here: first there is this loop over series - it will take ages once I have, say, 100 series with gaps. Maybe something like Numba? Then, I'm interpolating on copies any suggestions on how to do it inplace?

Thanks for having a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lengthy look for an answer it turns out there is no automated way of doing fillna based on gap length.

Conclusion: one can utilize the code from the question, the idea will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage interpolate's limit parameter.

```
df['ready'] = df.loc[df.group<10,['ser']].interpolate(method='linear',limit=9)
```

limit : int, default None.
Maximum number of consecutive NaNs to fill.

Then run interpolate() a second time with a different method or even run fillna()

Comment: Thank you for input with the limit parameter, but its not helping in this case - line you proposed would work exactly the same way without it. And in general using limit parameter would make all the gaps being filled up to specified length and its not what I'm looking for.